# Mockito answer is getting invoked only once

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock spring's applicationContext.getBean(String, Class) method in below manner -

```
when(applicationContext.getBean(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(SomeClass.class))).thenAnswer(
                new Answer<SomeClass>() {
                    @Override
                    public SomeClass answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                        // doing some stuff and returning the object of SomeClass
                }
        });
```

The scenario is that, the applicationContext.getBean method will be called a number of times, each time a with different strings but the same class (SomeClass.class).

The problem I am getting here is that the answer is getting invoked for the very first invocation of getBean method. With each subsequent invocation of getBean I am getting below exception -

```
******org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));******
```

Any idea, if I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

@Kshitij

I have faced same issue in my previous project. I came across this below doc:
http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.16.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#resetting_mocks

Under section 17 it is explained how to use reset()

Example: Let's say we have EvenOddService which finds whether number is even or odd then Test case with reset() will look like:

```
when(evenOddService.isEven(20)).thenReturn(true);
Assert.assertEquals(evenOddController.isEven(20), true);

//allows to reuse the mock
reset(evenOddService);
Assert.assertEquals(evenOddController.isEven(20), true);
```

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

When using Mockito, you need to tell him how many times you will call your mock. You need to make as many `when` calls as you will need. For instance, if you know you'll test your method three times, you need to declare three separate `when` statements.

PS: I used Mockito for a bit only, it is possible that there is a solution to tell Mockito to use the same `Answer` multiple times in a row.

---

**EDIT**

[Olivier Grégoire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180719/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) pointed out in the comments that you can use a single `when` call, but call `thenAnswer` multiple times. It is more elegant this way.

Comment: Instead of having several `when` calls, you can have only one followed by `.thenAnswer(...).thenAnswer(...).thenAnswer(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this to my test class:

```
@AfterEach
public void resetMock(){
    Mockito.reset(myMockedService);
}
```